# how to compress more jquery file

Tags: jquery

Can anybody help me with remaking function #open("var") and .post000("var")
I mean, when I click #open2 post will be post0002 and etc. Whant one function not 4 etc...
When I push link answer it shows me a form. And this js works fine, but it's too large and not usefull. I need to make universal js...

```
<div id="commentwindow">
        <form name="comment" action="#" method="post">
           <p><input class="name" type="text" maxlength="25" required placeholder="tell your name" formmethod="get"></p>
           <textarea  class="flud" required placeholder="insert text"></textarea>
           <p class="clearfix nopadding"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="add comment" formaction="#"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul class="postList">
        <li class="post post0004">
            <header>
                <span class="nameaccount">name</span>
                <span class="time">time</span>
            </header>
            <p>text</p>
            <footer>
                <a class="link open" id="open4" href="#open4">answer</a>
                <div class="empty"></div>
            </footer>
        </li>
        <li class="post post0002">
            <header>
                <span class="nameaccount">name</span>
                <span class="time">time</span>
            </header>
            <p>text</p>
            <footer>
                <a class="link open" id="open2" href="#open2">answer</a>
                <div class="empty"></div>
            </footer>
            <ul class="answer">
                <li class="post post0003">
                    <header>
                        <span class="nameaccount">name</span>
                        <span class="time">time</span>
                    </header>
                    <p></p>
                    <footer>
                        <a class="link open" id="open3" href="#open3">Answer</a>
                        <div class="empty1"></div>
                    </footer>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="post post0001">
            <header>
                <span class="nameaccount">name</span>
                <span class="time">time</span>
            </header>
            <p></p>
            <footer>
                <a class="link open" id="open1" href="#open1">Answer</a>
                <div class="empty"></div>
            </footer>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#open1").click(function() {
            var formContent = $("#commentwindow").html();
        $(".post0001 .empty").html(formContent);
            $(".post0003 .empty").html("");
            $(".post0004 .empty").html("");
            $(".post0002 .empty").html("");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#open2").click(function() {
            var formContent = $("#commentwindow").html();
            $(".post0002 .empty").html(formContent);
            $(".post0003 .empty1").html("");
            $(".post0004 .empty").html("");
            $(".post0001 .empty").html("");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#open3").click(function() {
            var formContent = $("#commentwindow").html();
            $(".post0003 .empty").html(formContent);
            $(".post0004 .empty").html("");
            $(".post0002 .empty").html("");
            $(".post0001 .empty").html("");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#open4").click(function() {
            var formContent = $("#commentwindow").html();
            $(".post0004 .empty").html(formContent);
            $(".post0003 .empty").html("");
            $(".post0002 .empty").html("");
            $(".post0001 .empty").html("");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish.  We'd also like to see the html.  To me it looks like you're trying to implement some sort of "tab" system without using jquery-ui.  Am I guessing right?

Comment: So where exactly are you having problems? Just run a loop and generate the selectors using some string concatenations.

Comment: Is there really meant to be a `1` after `empty` in the second `ready` block: `$(".post0003 .empty1").html("");`?

Comment: *"Can anybody help me with remaking function...Whant one function not 4 etc..."* Yes. And even better, my rates are quite reasonable. ;-)

Comment: Add html. It's Ul and li with empty div for form insert

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple selectors to target multiple elements:

```
$(".post0003 .empty").html("");
$(".post0004 .empty").html("");
$(".post0002 .empty").html("");
```

Becomes

```
$(".post0003 .empty, .post0004 .empty, .post0002 .empty").html("");
```

Both do the same thing.

You could compact it down even further by changing your open# elements to have a data attribute, for example:

```
<button id="open1" class="openButton" data-num="1">Click me</button>
```

Then what you'd do is have all the buttons use the same click handler:

```
$(".openButton").click(........);
```

And in the function do:

```
var num = $(this).data("num");
```

So now you know if it's button 1,2,3, etc.

Then you'd set all of the `.postXXXX` html contents to `""`, and only set the one that's different depending on the value of num.

All of this should massively compact the code and make it neater overall.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by picking up your clicked element id.
Try using this function.

```
function(event){
    var postNo = $(this).get('id');
    var postClass = "post000" + postNo.substr(4) 
    var formContent = $("#commentwindow").html();
    $(".empty").html("");
    $("." + postClass+" .empty").html(formContent);
}
```